# I'm getting the error "attempt to index local self (a number value)

Tags: lua

```
require 'class'
Paddle=class{}
function Paddle:init(x,y,width,height)
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.width=width
    self.height=height
    self.dy=0
end  function Paddle:update(dt)
    if self.dy < 0 then
        self.y = math.max(`enter code here`0, self.y + self.dy * dt)
    else
        self.y=math.min(VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,-self.height,self.y+self.dy*dt)
    end
end
function Paddle:render()
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill',self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)
end
```

I am following the course CS50 lecture 0 pong update 5, and the same code is working for the teacher. I don't know why this is happening neither understand the problem because it makes no sense. If you want, here's 'class'. This problem isn't happening in the other class I made called 'ball' which does exactly the same thing. I also defined self.dy, and it does have a value "0" so I don't know why it does that error and what that error means.

```
 local function include_helper(to, from, seen)
    if from == nil then
        return to
    elseif type(from) ~= 'table' then
        return from
    elseif seen[from] then
        return seen[from]
    end

    seen[from] = to
    for k,v in pairs(from) do
        k = include_helper({}, k, seen) -- keys might also be tables
        if to[k] == nil then
            to[k] = include_helper({}, v, seen)
        end
    end
    return to
end

-- deeply copies `other' into `class'. keys in `other' that are already
-- defined in `class' are omitted
local function include(class, other)
    return include_helper(class, other, {})
end

-- returns a deep copy of `other'
local function clone(other)
    return setmetatable(include({}, other), getmetatable(other))
end

local function new(class)
    -- mixins
    class = class or {}  -- class can be nil
    local inc = class.__includes or {}
    if getmetatable(inc) then inc = {inc} end

    for _, other in ipairs(inc) do
        if type(other) == "string" then
            other = _G[other]
        end
        include(class, other)
    end

    -- class implementation
    class.__index = class
    class.init    = class.init    or class[1] or function() end
    class.include = class.include or include
    class.clone   = class.clone   or clone

    -- constructor call
    return setmetatable(class, {__call = function(c, ...)
        local o = setmetatable({}, c)
        o:init(...)
        return o
    end})
end

-- interface for cross class-system compatibility (see https://github.com/bartbes/Class-Commons).
if class_commons ~= false and not common then
    common = {}
    function common.class(name, prototype, parent)
        return new{__includes = {prototype, parent}}
    end
    function common.instance(class, ...)
        return class(...)
    end
end


-- the module
return setmetatable({new = new, include = include, clone = clone},
    {__call = function(_,...) return new(...) end})
```

So this is the part where I call the update function, which is what someone said might be the error

```
function love.update(dt)
if love.keyboard.isDown('w') then
    player1.dy=-PADDLE_SPEED
elseif love.keyboard.isDown('s') then
    player1.dy=PADDLE_SPEED
else
    player1.dy=0
end
if love.keyboard.isDown('up') then
    player2.dy=-PADDLE_SPEED
elseif love.keyboard.isDown('down') then
    player2.dy=PADDLE_SPEED
else
    player2.dy=0
end
if gameState=='play' then
    ball.update(dt)
end
player1.update(dt)
player2.update(dt)
```

Comment: You pasted your code wrong: ``math.max(`enter code here`0``

Comment: Also, can you post a stack trace, and point out which lines correspond to the line numbers in it?

Comment: Change all of your occurrences of `.update` to `:update` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: you have a typo in the second line. replace `class{}` with `Class{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is pretty clear on what you're doing wrong.

You're indexing local self, a number value.

That means that somewhere you're doing something like `self.dy` where `self` is not a table but a number and using the index operator `.` on numbers is not allowed as it does not make any sense.

The question is why self is not a table.

```
function myTable:myFunction() end
```

is short (syntactic sugar) for

```
function myTable.myFunction(self) end
```

and the function call

`myTable:myFunction()`  is short for `myTable.myFunction(myTable)`

Please refer to the Lua manual.

[Function Calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10)

[Function Definitions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11)

Find a function in your code that is defined with `:` and called with `.` and gets a number as first argument during that call.

That way a number ends up where you expect `self`.

I guess the error is in the main.lua which you did not provide.

There you have several calls to `Paddle:update(dt)`.  Writing `myPaddle.update(dt)` would cause that error for example. But I can't tell for sure as you did not provide your code.

But that it works for the teacher, but not for you is usually because you do something different/wrong.

**Edit:**

As you've provided more code I can tell for sure that the observed error is caused by

```
ball.update(dt)
player1.update(dt)
player2.update(dt)
```

This will put `dt` a number value, where the function expects `self`, the table ball.

replace it by

`ball.update(ball, dt)` or `ball:update(dt)`

`player1.update(player1, dt)` or `player1:update(dt)`

`player2.update(player2, dt)` or `player2:update(dt)`

Comment: I don't get it, how do I get self.dy to equal 0, and it does, but make it make sense? This is the link for the full code used by my teacher https://github.com/games50/pong/blob/master/pong-5/Paddle.lua

Comment: If I try to use perfectly the class function that my teacher uses I get error attempt to call global 'Class' (a nil value)

Comment: @RafaelCarvalho you're getting an error for calling global 'class', not 'Class' because you wrote 'class' instead of 'Class'. The code uses capital C while you try to use c which of course does not work as Lua names are case sensitive. Mind the details!!!

Comment: In the code I posted, yes, but when I switch to using Paddle= Class{} it says nil value, but If I use the normal class, it doesn't work because of the index number thing, which I think should be solved by the class module, which isn't working properly.

Comment: woah somehow changing it to player1:update(dt) and doing the same thing to all of them worked thank you so much!!!!

Comment: that's why I wrote that answer. ;) you should read them from time to time. and learn a few more Lua basics befor you continue that game stuff. Its too complicated for a beginner.